# Is there a way to copy only views from a Sharepoint 2010 library to SharePoint online library?

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, office365, sharepoint-online

I have a SharePoint Online 2010 site, I have migrated all the content from SP 2010 to SPO. Now I want to only recreate the views from the source site (SP 2010). Because there are so many views, doing it manually is going to take a lot of time. So, is there any chance that I can recreate the views same as the one's in the source using Powershell or any other language?

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to "logs"/"reports" in SharePoint online, it is not so easy to get them, but still I have managed to found a couple of ways. Check this article that I have wrote about how to get user's activities in SPO: https://www.alight.ro/Articles/Efficient-Ways-to-monitor-Site-Collection/

It contains both manually and programmatically ways.
If you prefer to do it **programmatically**, the best way is by using **Exchange Online module** . By using a simple command "Search-UnifiedAuditLog" you can get all kind of activities users have performed on a file: download, view, edit etc. And all you have to do is to write a script. See sample code:

[enter image description here][1]

In the article you will find what represents each line of code.